# Tensor("conv2d_1/kernel:0", shape=(9, 9, 1, 64), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 352, 288, 1)

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to apply keras functional model. I don't quite understand why the input size are not compatible with convolutional layers.

I tried to use a sequential model to plug-in as one functional layer, but the problem still exists.

```
# if input shape = (TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH, 1),
#     You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,352,288,1]
# if input shape = (AMOUNT, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH),
#     number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 288 != 1
# if input shape = (TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH, AMOUNT)
#     number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 300 != 1
# if input shape = (AMOUNT, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH, 1),
#     input tensor must have rank 4
# if shape = (AMOUNT, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH), data_format='channels_last'
#     Input() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_format'
```

If I use functional model to do the implementation, the compiler says tensor of SRCNN1 conv layer  must be from the same graph as Tensor of input.

```py
def base_model_SRCNN(FILENAME, HEIGHT, WIDTH):

    par = load_parameter(FILENAME)  #load transfer learning parameters

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (9,9), padding = 'same', activation ='relu', use_bias = True,
    input_shape=(HEIGHT,WIDTH, 1), trainable = False))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', use_bias = True, trainable = True))
    model.add(Conv2D(1, (5, 5), padding='same', activation = 'relu', use_bias = True, trainable = True))

    for i in range(3):
        model.layers[i].set_weights(par[i])

    print(model.summary())

    model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = adam(lr=0.0005, decay=1e-6), metrics=[ssim_for2d, psnr_for2d])

    return model


def combined(FILENAME, AMOUNT, DEPTH, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH):
    ip = Input(shape = (TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH, 1))

    tf.reset_default_graph()
    #SRCNN_network = base_model_SRCNN(FILENAME, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH) (ip)  

    SRCNN1 = Conv2D(64, (9, 9), padding = 'same', activation ='relu', use_bias = True, 
     data_format='channels_last', trainable = False) (ip)  #input_shape=(TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH, 1),

    SRCNN2 = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', use_bias = True, trainable = True) (SRCNN1)

    SRCNN3 = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), padding='same', activation = 'relu', use_bias = True, trainable = True) (SRCNN2)

model = combined(FILENAME, AMOUNT, DEPTH, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH)

#AMOUNT, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH = 300, 352, 288
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "main.py", line 71, in <module>
    model = combined(FILENAME, AMOUNT, DEPTH, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH)
  File "/home/user1/REUS/image-reconstruction/code/functional/model_build_up.py", line 51, in combined
    data_format='channels_last', trainable = False) (ip)  #input_shape=(TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH, 1),
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 171, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3650, in conv2d
    data_format=tf_data_format)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 838, in convolution
    with ops.name_scope(name, "convolution", [input, filter]) as name:
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6083, in __enter__
    g = _get_graph_from_inputs(self._values)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5713, in _get_graph_from_inputs
    _assert_same_graph(original_graph_element, graph_element)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5649, in _assert_same_graph
    original_item))
ValueError: Tensor("conv2d_1/kernel:0", shape=(9, 9, 1, 64), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 352, 288, 1), dtype=float32).
```

Comment: The error is not  about shapes but about different graphs, why are you resetting the graph at all? That introduces this problem.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I delete the graph reset and the model can be compiled, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there are multiple tensorflow computational graphs, and that you are trying to combine operations from different graphs, this won't work.

This happens because you are using `tf.reset_default_graph()`, which I don't think it is needed at all, please try without it.